# Determine the minimum size, in bits, of each of the four inter-stage registers

Tags: architecture, mips

I have no idea on how to begin approaching this question.

Any hints on it or reference which
I could read/videos etc that would enable me to answer this would be great
Consider the multi-cycle MIPS datapath presented in Figure 1,
it shows 4 inter-stage registers: IF/ID, ID/EX, EX/MEM, and MEM/WB. Consider also
the control signals presented in the diagram in blue. Assume the ALUOp control signal is
3 bits. Ignore control signals not shown (i.e. the ones controlling forwarding). Determine
the minimum size, in bits, of each of the four inter-stage registers

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are saying that we shall consider each of the the 4 inter-stage blocks as being composed of a single "register", and are asking how wide each inter-stage's such register is.

You can see fairly clearly that the IF/ID inter-stage block has a "register" that receives as input — and thus holds: (a) the instruction read from instruction memory, and (b) the program counter+4 computation.  Since each of these items (a,b) is 32 bits wide, then the IF/ID "register" must be 64 bits wide, in order to hold both of these values.  (There appear to be no control signals in the IF/ID register.)

The ID/EX inter-stage block also receives (a) the bit program counter, (b) the read data 1 and 2, (c) the sign extended immediate, (d) the `rt` and `rd` instruction fields, and (e) three control signals.  So, reason how wide each of these are and sum them to get the width of the ID/EX stage register.  (Note that the EX portion of the register has 3 out signals, and that the text says one of them is 3 bits wide... Unless otherwise noted, we count 1 bit of width for a control signal as most of them are simple booleans.)

In summary, compute how many bits are going in or going out of the inter-stage register and that's the answer for that inter-stage.  (The number of bits going in and going out are equal — the register is just copying bits directly from "in" (diagrammed to the left of the register with incoming arrows) and the end of one cycle, to "out" at the beginning of the next (diagrammed with arrows coming out from the right of the register).)

---

This diagram is an oversimplification.  For example, in order to implement bypass/forwarding and/or stalls in the EX stage, `rs` also needs to be communicated from ID to EX, but only `rt` and `rd` are shown as being shared.  There is also the need for bypass/forwarding in the MEM stage, so that also needs the various register fields of the instruction.